# Deserializing JSON (without dynamic) where array has multiple possible depths based on value of another property?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON without using `dynamic` as it is not supported by my system: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vansha/Two10.CountryLookup/master/Two10.CountryLookup/region-list.json

Each line presents a region for geolocating with.

Using the JSON Converter here: https://json2csharp.com/

I get the suggestion for data classes as:

```
    // Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegionJsonObject>(myJsonResponse);

    public class Geometry {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<List<List<List<double>>>> coordinates { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegionJsonObject {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Properties properties { get; set; }
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem is that if you look at the JSON, there are actually two possible formats for the `coordinates` array. If the `Geometry.type` is `Polygon` we have three levels of depth `[[[ ]]]` and if it is `MultiPolygon` we get four levels of depth `[[[[ ]]]]`. So I am instead considering a format of the following with a custom JsonConverter:

```
    class GeometryConverter : JsonConverter {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
            return (objectType == typeof(Geometry));
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {

            Geometry geometry = new Geometry();

            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            geometry.type = jo["type"].Value<string>();

            if (geometry.type == "Polygon") {
                geometry.coordinatesPolygon = jo["coordinates"].Value<List<List<List<double>>>>(); //DOESN'T WORK
            }
            else {
                geometry.coordinatesMulipolygon = jo["coordinates"].Value<List<List<List<List<double>>>>>(); //DOESN'T WORK
            }

            return geometry;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            // If you want to support serializing you could implement this method as well
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class Geometry {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public List<List<List<List<double>>>> coordinatesMulipolygon { get; set; } //multipolygon
        public List<List<List<double>>> coordinatesPolygon { get; set; } //polygon
    }

    public class Properties {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegionJsonObject {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Properties properties { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("geometry")]
        [JsonConverter(typeof(GeometryConverter))] 
        public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    }

}
```

However, this is not working. Trying to set `geometry.coordinatesPolygon` or `geometry.coordinatesMultipolygon` in this manner gives the error:

`InvalidCastException: Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.`

Am I on the right track with this approach? How do I get the arrays from the JSON into each of these two list objects as needed? Is there a better or more proper way?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe use polymorphism for your geometry : one class `Polygon` and one class `Multipolygon`.
Then you can use [JsonSubTypes](https://manuc66.github.io/JsonSubTypes/) converter.

You have also a stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57478056/c-sharp-newtonsoft-json-deserializing-object-with-collection-of-unknown-object)

Comment: Thanks! Interesting other approaches. My approach actually worked. I just had to change it to:  `jo["coordinates"].ToObject<List<...>>` rather than using `Value` here.

Answer (score 1):

```
            if (geometry.type == "Polygon") {
                geometry.coordinatesPolygon = jo["coordinates"].ToObject<List<List<List<double>>>>(); //WORKS
            }
            else {
                geometry.coordinatesMulipolygon = jo["coordinates"].ToObject<List<List<List<List<double>>>>>(); //WORKS
            }
```

This solved it.